# Sort array and SUM item counts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array

```
[
  {
    itemId: 'id1',
    itemColor: 'red',
    itemSize: 'xxl',
    itemCount: **10**  <------
  },
  {
    itemId: 'id1',
    itemColor: 'red',
    itemSize: 'xxl',
    itemCount: **5**  <------
  },{
    itemId: 'id2',
    itemColor: 'green',
    itemSize: 'xl',
    itemCount: **10**  <------
  },{
    itemId: 'id2',
    itemColor: 'green',
    itemSize: 'xl',
    itemCount: **125**  <------
  },{
    itemId: 'id3',
    itemColor: 'yellow',
    itemSize: 'xxl',
    itemCount: **1000**  <------
  },
]
```

I need to first sort this array and get the **sum** of **itemCount** where **itemId**, **itemColor** and **itemSize** is the **same**.

I need the result as below:

```
[
  {
    itemId: 'id1',
    itemColor: 'red',
    itemSize: 'xxl',
    itemCount: **15** <------<------<------ total item count for same ID
  },
  {
    itemId: 'id2',
    itemColor: 'green',
    itemSize: 'xl',
    itemCount: **135**  <------<------<------total item count for same ID
  }{
    itemId: 'id3',
    itemColor: 'yellow',
    itemSize: 'xxl',
    itemCount: **1000**  <------<------<------total item count for same ID
  },
]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Also DON'T paste Lorem ipsum to bypass what you are asked to provide!

Comment: But first [search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+object+by+id+site%3Astackoverflow.com) - reduce is a method you should look into

Comment: well,
thanks, apparently I'm too tired today

Comment: `const newArr = arr.reduce((acc,cur) => {
      const exists = acc.find(({itemId,itemColor}) => itemId=== cur.itemId && itemColor === cur.itemColor);
      if (exists) exists.itemCount+=cur.itemCount;
      else acc.push(cur);
      return acc; },[])`